# Update table doesn't work with a real device (fmdb)

Tags: swift, fmdb

I am newbie in iOS development and i have a problem. I am trying to update a table with FMDB but although it has worked in all simulators it doesn't work on a real device. I am sure that the db has been transferred to the device because all the select queries are running properly. On the other hand all the update queries not. 
I have tried to use NSNumber or NSInteger but ... nothing.

```
if (database.open())
    {
        let rs = database.executeQuery("update \(TABLE_NAME) set x=1 where id=\(y.getId())",withArgumentsInArray: nil)
        //database.executeUpdate("update \(TABLE_NAME) set x=1 where id=?", withArgumentsInArray:[NSInteger(y.getId())])
        database.close()
    }
```

Neither of the above solutions works.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the db file was in the bundle Resources that is read-only.
When i copied the db file to the Documents folder everything worked fine.

I found on http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/use-sqlite-database-swift

this piece of code

```
class func copyFile(fileName: NSString) {
    let dbPath: String = getPath(fileName as String)
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(dbPath) {

        let documentsURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourceURL
        let fromPath = documentsURL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName as String)

        var error : NSError?
        do {
            try fileManager.copyItemAtPath(fromPath.path!, toPath: dbPath)
        } catch let error1 as NSError {
            error = error1
        }
        let alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
        if (error != nil) {
            alert.title = "Error Occured"
            alert.message = error?.localizedDescription
        } else {
            alert.title = "Successfully Copy"
            alert.message = "Your database copy successfully"
        }
        alert.delegate = nil
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
        alert.show()
    }
}
```

The code with the UIAlertView is an extra, You can omit it.